# How to upload image and preview at once?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jQuery to upload files to server (PHP) and at the server side I process the uploaded files to create image previews (with Nette Framework), then save original files and previews, but it seems to be really slow.
Is there a way to create the preview BEFORE file is uploaded and then upload file AND preview at once, instead of processing it on the server side?
Thank you

Comment: I don't want to show the preview. I want to upload it to the server, which I can't find anywhere in the documentation. :/

Comment: If "*..I don't want to show the preview*". Then, what is this "*...Is there a way to create the preview BEFORE file is uploaded..*"

Comment: I want to create the preview as a "file", then upload file AND the preview which would be smaller image, instead of creating the smaller image at the server side. So basically - user select files to upload, then presses submit, then JS should process selected files and create smaller images than the original ones, then original files and these "previews" get uploaded to the server. Of course it is possible to show these previews in the meantime, but it is not what I want. And these previews get later loaded from the database to show on website, instead of the original.